# fortran fgldrawpixels character*8 pointer to data

Tags: opengl, fortran

I am trying to visualize a 2D real array in fortran95 using opengl with intel parallel studio in msvs. For this I have found (trying to understand) `fglDrawPixels` on http://polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=fgldrawpixels&tf=2&of=IRIX&sf=3

In the explanation of the subroutine

```
SUBROUTINE fglDrawPixels( INTEGER*4 width,
               INTEGER*4 height,
               INTEGER*4 format,
               INTEGER*4 type,
               CHARACTER*8 pixels )
```

it says that pixels

> Specifies a pointer to the pixel data.

I don't fully understand this, since the data I whant to show is real(4) (or GL_FLOAT) How do I declare a pointer that I can use??? (character*8 to a pointer to real(4) data) - I thought this would be declared as `real(4), pointer, dimension(:,:) :: pixels` but that does not seem to be what `fglDrawPixels` expects...

Any help or hint on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That description of the routine's interface is incorrect. The pixels argument is of type integer(K_GLvoid), or in other words, an address-sized integer. It is NOT a Fortran pointer. Typically you would use LOC(buffer) here where buffer is whatever variable you're using to hold the pixel data. All these arguments are passed by value, and the calling convention is STDCALL.

If you are using Intel Visual Fortran, module IFOPNGL declares this with the correct interface.